# Is there a better/faster way to access raw data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This isn't related to a particular issue BUT is a question regarding "best practise".

For a while now, when I need to get data straight from the database I've been using the following method - I was wondering if there's a faster method which I don't know about?

```
DataTable results = new DataTable();
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"]))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName",connection))
    {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      /*Optionally set command.Parameters here*/
      results.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
/*Do something useful with the results*/
```

Comment: Looks fine, are you experiencing delays?

Comment: I think that you should look at your stored procedure code and not here

Comment: Why do you think that ther's something faster? You could use a `SqlDataAdapter` to [`fill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk.aspx) the table, but i doubt that that would change anything.

Comment: Not experiencing any problems as such - just wanted to double check my understanding and see if this is the best approach for this scenario.

Comment: @bUKaneer - if your queries are working and returning the results in a acceptable time I would suggest theres not much more you can do aside limit the data being returned to improve performance (which in your case doesn't seem to be necessary).

Comment: @Darren Davies Thanks for the input - I don't have a massive circle of dev types I can ask this type of question to so figured SO was a good place to double check my own knowledge. Not entirely sure if its in the spirit of the site but didn't seem to be against the rules in the FAQ!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed various ways of reading data; `DataTable` is quite a complex beast (with support for a number of complex scenarios - referential integrity, constraints, computed values, on-the-fly extra columns, indexing, filtering, etc). In a lot of cases you *don't need all that*; you just want the data. To do that, a simple object model can be more efficient, both in memory and performance. You could write your own code around `IDataReader`, but that is a solved problem, with a range of tools that do that for you. For example, you could do that via [dapper](http://nuget.org/packages/Dapper) with just:

```
class SomeTypeOfRow { // define something that looks like the results
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    //..
}
...
var rows = connection.Query<SomeTypeOfRow>("StoredProcedureName",
    /* optionalParameters, */ commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

which then very efficiently populates a `List<SomeTypeOfRow>`, without all the `DataTable` overheads. Additionally, if you are dealing with very large volumes of data, you can do 
this in a fully streaming way, so you don't need to buffer 2M rows in memory:

```
var rows = connection.Query<SomeTypeOfRow>("StoredProcedureName",
    /* optionalParameters, */ commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure,
    buffered: false); // an IEnumerable<SomeTypeOfRow>
```

For completeness, I should explain `optionalParameters`; if you wanted to pass `@id=1`, `@name="abc"`, that would be just:

```
var rows = connection.Query<SomeTypeOfRow>("StoredProcedureName",
    new { id = 1, name = "abc" },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
```

which is, I think you'll agree, a pretty concise way of describing the parameters. This parameter is entirely optional, and can be omitted if no parameters are required.

As an added bonus, it means you get strong-typing for free, i.e.

```
foreach(var row in rows) {
    Console.WriteLine(row.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(row.Name);
}
```

rather than having to talk about `row["Id"]`, `row["Name"]` etc.

Comment: Thats just blown me away and was EXACTLY what I wanted! I shall go forth and play with this approach. You just made my day! ;o) *Big Grin*

Comment: @bUKaneer I am somewhat biased towards dapper (we wrote it as part of the data-access layer for Stack Exchange), but: other similar tools exist: Simple.Data, PetaPoco, Massive etc - and that's just the light-weight tools. There are heaving tools too; NHibernate, Entity Framework, LLBLGenPro, LINQ-to-SQL, etc

Comment: Yes I did notice you're author on nuget ;o) I've used EF and LINQ-to-SQL in the past with success but always felt they were heavy and potentially slower than the more direct approaches. I like to know how things work and why from the bottom up (CLR via C# is my Bible) and then use/implement them. Ill go and pull dapper and have a poke about!

Comment: @bUKaneer the code is all available; it uses ILGenerator (cached) extensively, so how much sense it makes depends on how familiar you are with IL ;p

Comment: Hey Marc just thought Id drop you a note to thank you again - Im loving Dapper! Started tinkering and have created a blog post with basic example - truely brilliant! http://ilovedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/adonet-dappernet-using-c-aspnet.html

Comment: @bUKaneer looks good; note: in recent builds, you don't even need to open the connection ;p

Comment: Hi @Marc added a benchmark post too - your comment regarding connections is noted ;o) http://ilovedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/adonet-datatables-vs-dappernet.html